# Video canplay event triggers thousands of times per second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have the following jQuery code in my page onload function:

```
$("#vid-pages").find("video").on('canplay', function() {
  $(this)[0].currentTime = $(this)[0].duration / 2;
  console.log($(this)[0].currentTime);
});
```

There are only two videos in that container, and none anywhere else on the page. When I check the console, it's continuously flooded with the time returned in that code block. What is the solution to make this trigger only once, instead of constantly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the current time is changed the browser needs to load more data either from cache or the network. This can trigger the `canplay` event. And since a time is set in the event handler you will get a never-ending loop (you can see the effect of `canplay` being triggered **[here](https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)** by choosing a video, hit play then skip to the middle right after). It may depend on the browser.

**[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)** on MDN states the following to the related **canplaythrough** (though not entirely the same it is reasonable to believe this also applies to `canplay` as shown in the media event page using Firefox):

> Note: Manually setting the currentTime will eventually fire a
>   canplaythrough event in firefox. Other browsers might not fire this
>   event.

To avoid either unsubscribe from the event, or use a *flag* which forces exit at the second time the event is triggered.

```
var initialPlay = false;

$("#vid-pages").find("video").on('canplay', function() {
  if (initialPlay) return;
  initialPlay = true;

  $(this)[0].currentTime = $(this)[0].duration / 2;
  console.log($(this)[0].currentTime);
});
```

For unsubscribing you would need to use a non-anonymous function.